# Insert data if it does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert some data in my column only if my query parameters are not already added.

For example, if my row contains :

```
a=4&b=7&c=9
```

and now, when update happens with : b=7&c=9, then i should not append it.

```
o/p:a=4&b=7&c=9
```

But if update happens with d=9&e=9
then it should append it.

```
o/p : a=4&b=7&c=9&d=9&e=9
```

My normal Update query is :

```
@AdditionalParams = 'b=7&c=9'
SELECT @id = mid FROM Table2 WHERE sid = @SId
                AND cid = @CId;

            UPDATE Table1
            SET additional_params = CONCAT (
                    additional_params
                    ,iif(additional_params IS NULL, NULL, '&')
                    ,@AdditionalParams
                    )
            WHERE mid = @id
```

How can i use here the NOT EXIST Clasue.

But with not exist clause it checks whole row, I just want to check if parameters exist, then dont insert it.

Comment: that's a pretty terrible way to store data

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for a not like clause

```
declare @AdditionalParams varchar(50) = 'b=7&c=8'
SELECT @id = mid 
   FROM Table2 
  WHERE sid = @SId
   AND cid = @CId;

  UPDATE Table1
  SET additional_params = CONCAT (
                     additional_params
                    ,iif(additional_params IS NULL, NULL, '&')
                    ,@AdditionalParams
                    )
   WHERE mid = @id
     and additional_params not like '%'+ @AdditionalParams +'%';
```